# Can i use EclEmma coverage report in sonar?

Tags: java, code-coverage, sonarqube, eclemma

I have to generate a code coverage for unit tests on sonar.Eclipse provide eclEmma for providing code coverage by unit tests.I am able to generate coverage report using eclEmmma 2.0,How can i use this report to configure with sonar analysis...or any other method for getting unit test code coverage in sonar..?

Answer (score 2):

Out-of-the box Sonar supports Jacoco (embedded into lastest versions of eclEmma) and Cobertura engine to report code coverage by unit tests. If you have a Maven project, this code coverage will be automatically computed by Sonar. Otherwise, you can ask Sonar to import existing reports, see http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project